# Estou tantando colocar o titulo da imagem em minha galeria Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Olá, estou tentando chamar o o titulo da imagem, para ser exibido na galeria, mas é chamado somente o titulo da primeira fotos e todas as outras estão com o mesmo titulo, será que poderiam me ajudar?

Segue meu código:

```
<?php

        $imagens_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

        $imagens = array();

        $imagens[] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();

        foreach ($imagens_ids as $imagem_id) {

            $imagens[] = wp_get_attachment_url($imagem_id);             
          $title = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_title;       
      }


        echo '<div class="images galeria-imagens-produto">';

            echo '<div class="galeria-maior">';

                foreach ($imagens as $imagem) {


                    echo '<div class="bloco-imagem-maior">';

                        echo '<div class="h-100 bloco-imagem-maior-interno">';

                            echo '<a data-fancybox="galeria_'.get_the_ID().'" href="'.$imagem.'">';

                                echo '<img src="'.$imagem.'" class="h-100 w-100" alt="'.get_the_title($imagem_id).'">';

                            echo '</a>';

                        echo'</div>';

                        echo '<div class="legenda-imagem">';

                            echo '<p>'.$title.'</p>';

                        echo'</div>';

                    echo'</div>';

                }

            echo'</div>';

        echo'</div>';

        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você tem os ids das imagens, tente isso:

```
get_the_title($imagem_id)
```